# convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^{\alpha})(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n}tdt)x^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

We are given $$\displaystyle W_n =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n}tdt.$$
Find the radius of convergence of the power series
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{W_n}{n^{\alpha}}x^n$$ in terms of alpha.

How to do this? So far I only managed to get $W_{n+2}+W_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$. But how to apply this for any convergence test?

Comment: How to do this? So far I only managed to get $W_{n+2}+W_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}$. But how to apply this for any convergence test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in the interval $[0, \pi/4]$ we have that $0 \leq \tan x \leq 1$. But then we have that
\begin{align*}
\tan^{n+1}(x) &\leq \tan^n(x) \\
\int_0^{\pi/ 4}\tan^{n+1}(x)dx &\leq \int_0^{\pi/ 4}\tan^{n}(x)dx \\
W_{n+1} &\leq W_n
\end{align*}
Now, I'll prove that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{W_n}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Using the equality you derived, we have that
\begin{gather*}
\frac{2W_{n+2}}{\frac{1}{n+1}} \leq \frac{W_n + W_{n+2}}{\frac{1}{n+1}} = 1 \leq \frac{2W_n}{\frac{1}{n+1}} \\
\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \leq W_n \qquad \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \geq W_{n+2} \Rightarrow W_n \leq \frac{1}{2(n-1)} \\
\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \leq W_n \leq \frac{1}{2(n-1)}
\end{gather*}
Applying squeeze limit, we get the limit exist and is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Finally, we apply ratio test
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{W_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^\alpha}}{\frac{W_{n}x^{n}}{n^\alpha}} \right| = |x| \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{W_{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{\frac{W_{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}} \frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}} = |x|
\end{align*}
Thus, $R = 1$

Comment: i didnt get the final line. How you get $n^{\alpha+1}$?

Comment: gess so. maybe the correct term is $\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{(n+1)^{\alpha-1}}$

Comment: I corrected it. Note that you divide through by $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$ and not by $n+1$ and $n$. That changes the powers to $\alpha+1$.

Comment: Does it means radius of convergence does not depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes it does not, which is not that surprising. Think about the power seires $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^\alpha}$ for instance.

Comment: ok. thanks much